# do I have to load the whole module ,If I have a component and I want to use it in another component in angular 13?

Tags: angular, rxjs

In angular 13 ,If I have a shared module contain a component and I want to use that component in another component or another module, do I have to load the whole shared module or there another way?

Comment: Yes you do. If you are not confortable with that extract that component to a separate module.

Comment: You have to import the shared module to other module. That is why it is called shared module

Comment: There is a SCAM (single component angular module) pattern you can work with if shared module isn't working for you. Downside is declaring lots of imports vs 1 shared module import.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
This is the Angular concept.

`Component` declared inside `Module`. and this `Module` can be imported into another `Module` - and then you can use this component.

Pay attention that Angular v14 is available, and this version include concept called *StandAloneComponent*...
this concept allows you to declare a method as stand-alone so you can import it directly to other components.

you can read about this concept here [here](https://angular.io/guide/standalone-components)